# Запуск нескольких экземпляров программы через код C#

Tags: c#, windows, .net, процесс

Есть программы, несколько экземпляров которых обычным способом запустить нельзя.
К примеру несколько экземпляров Skype запустить на одном ПК  не получается.

Можно ли это ограничение как-нибудь обойти через C#?
Я пробовал использовать Process.Start, но не помогло.

Comment: Контроль других экземпляров часто осуществляется через глобальные объекты типа Event или Mutex. Насколько я помню, контролировать их через CreateProcess нельзя.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Обычно функциональность «разрешить запускать только один экземпляр программы» реализуется внутри самой программы. Когда второй экземпляр программы стартует, он каким-то образом (одним из миллиона возможных) проверяет, что первый экземпляр программы уже запущен, и просто немедленно завершает работу.

Поэтому вы не сможете так просто обмануть программу, вам придётся зареверсить её. Не удивляйтесь, что даже если вы сможете обманом запустить два экземпляра программы, она может работать неправильно — например, падать.

---

Более правильный путь — не пытаться обмануть чужую программу, а просто попросить её. Вполне возможно, разработчики программы предоставили нужную вам возможность. Например, второй экземпляр Скайпа можно запустить с [ключом /secondary](https://support.skype.com/ru/faq/FA829/kak-ispol-zovat-neskol-ko-ucetnyh-zapisej-v-skype-dla-windows-desktop).